# Broken ankle, can't use kickstarter. How can I work on my dirt bike engine?

Tags: motorcycle, tools

I'm working on a kickstart-only 1991 DR350 that doesn't run. Unfortunately I recently broke my right ankle so I'm not really able to use the kickstart lever, and there aren't any hills near my workshop that I could use to bump-start it.

Is there some kind of tool that I can use to turn over the engine for my testing? I'm picturing some kind of an electric-powered wheel that can be mechanically pressed into contact with the rear wheel to get it spinning. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You could always use your left foot while not stradling the bike? I'd suspect since you are working on the bike, you're using your right foot while in a cast or boot anyways? Just be gentle on it ... just a thought.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2's idea would work fine as long as you have a way to keep the bike stable.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJka2vpSaQ0

Comment: As medical advice is frowned upon this is a comment. Ask your doctor for his/her opinion on potential for more damage by doing this. My guess is he/her would strongly advise against doing it.  Have someone else start it then do what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

That's a tough one. I'd say you're best bet is to stabilize the bike and start it with your left foot like on this Harley [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJka2vpSaQ0)

To stabilize it I would recommend tying the bike down as even putting it on the kickstand or a moto stand would probably not keep it stable enough.